# Sending redirect to another servlet/JSP without loosing the request parameters.

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How do i specify a redirection to another servlet, in the doPost() method of a servlet.

at the moment I'm using

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

which is wrong since, my parameters in the doGet() method of products are not being called and initialized.

So I'm left with an empty products page after logging in :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) to send a redirect. Assuming that the servlet is mapped on an URL pattern of `/products`:

```
response.sendRedirect("/products");
```

This way the webbrowser will be instructed to fire a new HTTP GET request on the given URL and thus the `doGet()` method of the servlet instance will be called where you can in turn load the products and forward to a JSP which displays them the usual way.

Comment: If I'm setting an attribute

request.setAttribute("test",new String("ABC"));

how do i access it in the other servlet.

Comment: Depends on the functional requirement. If it's the logged-in user, you should store it in the session. Or if it is request based data, then pass it as request parameter. Or if it's actually the responsibility of the products servlet, you should do it there.

Answer (score 1):

In your doPost you can always call:

```
return doGet(request, response);
```

Comment: I believe that you don't understand the problem. Regardless, porting GET to POST or vice versa is in any way a poor practice. You should use GET to preprocess requests and use POST to postprocess requests and not mix up them.