# Accesing request attribute in jsp not having direct access to request

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am using struts 1.2.In an action class I am getting result which i put in request as an attribute.i.e request.setAttribute("contarctNumber","123BB4").

Now the thing is that i am getting redirected to multiple other pages after setting this attribute which ultimately redirect to a JSP.I want to show this request attribute on this jsp but this does not have access to request object/attribute.How can i access this request attribute in my JSP?

Comment: you have a great avatar, like sun :)

Answer (score 0):

Via EL you can find it.

Just put this in your **jsp**:

```
${contarctNumber}
```

---

***EDIT:***

See if this post helps:

[Sending redirect to another servlet/JSP without loosing the request parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539176/sending-redirect-to-another-servlet-jsp-without-loosing-the-request-parameters)

Comment: isnt this when the action class redirects directly to jsp.in my case it is not directly redirecting to the jsp.there are multiple intermediate pages to which redirection takes  place

Comment: Maybe, in this case, your attribute should be set in the sessionScope. Did you try it?

Comment: LIke this: request.getSession().setAttribute("contarctNumber","123BB4")

Comment: yes thats what i thought and tried too but this has to be for the current request only not for a new tab that user opens in the same session so cant put that in the session scope.any other way?