# call servlet from controller with parameters to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am writing a jsp file to call a controller with some parameters. And from this controller i want to call a servlet by passing the values from the controller. And with in the servlet i should get access to the parameters. Is it possible to forward values from jsp to servlet via controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending redirect to another servlet/JSP without loosing the request parameters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539176/sending-redirect-to-another-servlet-jsp-without-loosing-the-request-parameters)

Comment: possible that link may be a different one. Here i am using spring framework, firstly i am forwarding my request to the controller later on to the sevlet page. And i dont need any response from the controller.

Comment: that is not worth able. That is complete irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yes it's possible in Spring controller,

Try this in Spring controller:

public void requestedURL(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){

String jspParameter = request.getParameter("param_name");
req.getRequestDispatcher("your servlet url pattern?param1="+jspParameter)
                                     .forward(req, res);

}
```

Comment: which is exactly what the duplicate link is doing.

Comment: it is showing 404 exception. if u give the servlet url in the request dispatcher. I have already configured the url pattern in the web.xml. still showing 404

Comment: Just add context path prefix to your servlet url.Example: req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath()+"your servlet url pattern?param1="+jspParameter).forward(req, res);

Comment: Done with great success. TQ Mr. Surendra Kannan.