# how to pass the same parameter from one JSP to two servlets? Then pass the different parameters from servlet to the same JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I was new to the web application. 
my issue: how to pass the same parameter from one JSP to two servlets? Then pass the different parameters from servlet to the same JSP?

important!! we should do the process A first then do the process B!!!!

As the project takes too many processes, I would like to separate the processes into two servlet.

Currently, I finish implement processA which is pass the search term from SEARCH PAGE JSP to SERVLET A (do the processA) and pass the result to WELCOME PAGE JSP. It works!!!(which i highlight in the red color in the picture)

the code I used:
Web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.processA</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download result</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Search page JSP:

```
<form   action="download result">           
             Please enter a Keyword <br> 
            <input type="text" name="term"size="20px">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

servletA:

```
public class processA  extends HttpServlet { 
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
          {
            // reading the user input

            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            // Retrieve search term from GET request and parse to desired format
            String searchTerm = (request.getParameter("term").toString()).replace("%20", "_").replace(" ", "_").replace("+", "_").replace(".", "");
            System.out.println("=====(servlet) searchTerm is:"+searchTerm);

  }

              protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
                  {
                 doGet(request, response);

          }  
                }
```

[image]

So how to implement the processB into the system??? which will look like the picture i showed.

the servletB

```
public class processB extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
          {
            doPost(request,response);
          }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {



        String searchTerm = (request.getParameter("term")).replace(" ", "_");
        String queryTerm = request.getParameter("term");

        System.out.println("=====(servlet) searchTerm is:"+searchTerm);

System.out.println("=====(servlet) keep doing the other process……………………!!!”);


}
}
```

thanks so much!
or if the doGET and doPOST cannot be used at the same time, I can change the processA to doPost.

important!! we should do the process A first then do the process B!!!!

Comment: In servletA, rather than forwarding to the jsp, redirect to servletB

Comment: u mean use servletA call servletB and pass the  String searchTerm from servletA to servletB???

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539176/sending-redirect-to-another-servlet-jsp-without-loosing-the-request-parameters

Answer (score 2):

There can be only one action **method**(get/post etc.) for your form of `SearchPage.jsp`.

You as a programmer have to decide first what and how the request needs to be process instead of letting users to choose between `doPost` and `doGet` methods.

Both the methods have different purposes check the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)

You have to keep both the processing units A and B into a single servlet(servletA/servletB),
**For example:** Call `Process A` first from JSP then call `Process B` from `Process A` and finally redirect/forward the response to `Welcome.jsp` from `Process B`
Below is the code:

**Search.jsp**

```
<form action="download result" method="get">
...
</form>
```

**servletA:**

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {
        ... //processing logic of A
        ... //processing logic of A
        ... //processing logic of A
        doPost(request,response);//call Post 
      }
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
        ... //processing logic of B
        ... //processing logic of B
        ... //processing logic of B

        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request, response);  
  }
```

**Note:** you can do viceversa, that is call `doPost` first and later `doGet` as per your requirement. Also, need to change `method="post"` in `form tag` for this.

---

For your query in comments use the below code:

**servletA:**

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {
        ... //processing logic of A
        ... //processing logic of A
        ... //processing logic of A
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("servletB");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);//call Post 
      }
```

**servletB:**

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
        ... //processing logic of B
        ... //processing logic of B
        ... //processing logic of B

        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request, response);  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I got the idea. but in your case, you combine servletA and servletB as the "new servletA".    however, I would like to keep two servlets . is it possible to use "response.sendRedirect( serveletB)" in the servletA ??

Comment: For this, you can keep two servlets by processing `servletA` first then use `requestdispatcher` to call `serlvetB` instead of redirect so that parameter values will be as it is. Later dispatch the request from `serlvetB` to welcome.jsp. Here, is an example where two servlets are used login and welcomeServlet http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher-in-servlet